# Why css tables only draw border around its rows and not include table-caption inside border?

Tags: css, css-tables

In css tables, I am noticing that if I add a border to `display: table;` element, it only draws border around all `display: table-row;` nodes, but not around `display: table-caption;` element, even if the table-caption node is a child of the `display: table;`. Why does it do so?

How do I get it to draw border around whole table (i.e. include table-caption inside the border)?

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate the point: https://jsfiddle.net/9028hswc/

Comment: because caption is not meant to be part of the data, i'd say ...

Comment: table caption is not part of the table itself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35543537/3597276

Comment: mind also the caption-side CSS rule :) https://jsfiddle.net/9028hswc/1/ (where it works ) so the borders ?

Comment: @Michael_B: You should post an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B. Thats useful info.

Comment: @BoltClock, I'm thinking maybe this question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35543313/3597276).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any element with the CSS property `display: table-caption` behaves like a `<caption>` element.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption):

> The HTML `<caption>` Element (or HTML Table Caption Element) represents the title of a table. Though it is always the first descendant of a , its styling, using CSS, may place it elsewhere, relative to the table.

So, technically, it's not part of the table and that's why it is not inside the border.

As 2-cents mentions in the comment, here is how you get the border around all of the content: https://jsfiddle.net/25zwopqr/

**Changes:**

HTML

```
<caption class='table-caption-div'>People Names</caption>
```

CSS

```
.table-caption-div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #cf0;
}
```

Comment: `caption {
display: inline-block;
}` will place it inside the border, if that's what he wants.

Comment: `caption { display: inline-block; }` will place it below `<thead>`.